# Biholomorphic map to a belt. Why?

Tags: complex-analysis

The exercise is this:
We have a set A = {z | |z-i|>1 and Im(z)>0} 
We want to find a biholomorphic map f that would map that area A into a belt.

So the solution is apparently f(z) = 1/z
which maps it to B = {z | -1/2 < Im(z) < 0}

My question is, how can you see that 1/z maps A that way? It's not really that logical for me. ( I can see that it maps everything to an area that has a negative imaginary part but I can't really see how it's a belt)

This is also somehow related to finding the solution and seeing it's a belt:
f(0) = inf
f(inf) = 0
f(2i) = -i/2

Comment: How is a "belt" defined?

Comment: @LeeMosher Looks like he calls the strip $-1/2 < Im(z) < 0$ a *belt*

Comment: Sorry, I guess a strip is the right word. (Wasn't sure what to put there, not a native english speaker)